# How can I multiply one column by a number, under some condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe,name a.

```
symbol  position    strategy    industry    Fund    EX Date Pay Date    Record Date Type    Net Rate    Gross Rate  Product Type
0   7203    44000.00    L   Trans.Equip.    59107   2021/03/30  2021/05/28  2021/03/31  Cash Dividend   102.00  120.00  EQ
1   6758    28500.00    L   Elec. App.  59107   2021/03/30  2021/06/04  2021/03/31  Cash Dividend   25.00   30.00   EQ
2   4063    12500.00    L   Chemicals   59107   2021/03/30  2021/06/29  2021/03/31  Cash Dividend   110.00  130.00  EQ
16  8306    256000.00   L   Banks   59107   2021/03/30  2021/06/30  2021/03/31  Cash Dividend   11.00   13.00   EQ
17  3003    115000.00   L   Real Estate 59107   NaN NaN NaN <NA>    nan nan <NA>
```

Now I want to add a new column that give me the position*Rate
then I want to multiply the new column by (-1) when my "strategy" is "S"
But this code gave me an error

```
a['Earning'] = a['position']*a['Net Rate']

def short(row):
    if row["strategy"] == 'S':
        return row['Earning'] *(-1)

a["final_earning"] = a.apply(short, axis=1)
```

last line of the error is

```
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

how can i get the "final earning".thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you want handle `NaN` value?

Comment: return NaN, or blank

Comment: `row['Earning']` could be `NaN` since `Net Rate` column contains `NaN`, you should handle this in your `short` method.

Comment: Don't apply, just use: `a.loc[a['strategy']=='S', 'Earning'] *= -1`.

Comment: @Quang Hoang understood. this one line works instead of the function. perfect. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import numpy as np

a['Earning'] = a["position"].mul(a["Net Rate"])

def short(row):
    if row["strategy"] == 'S' and not np.isnan(row["Earning"]):
        return row['Earning'] * (-1)
    return np.nan

a["final_earning"] = a.apply(short, axis=1)
```

The Pandas `mul` function deals with `nan` values for you.

Comment: it extract this error --> TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. I edited my answer to check for `nan` values in your `short` function too.